# How to map AWS API Gateway route path to a different path in the integration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-elb

Suppose I have created an AWS API Gateway.  For a route with route key "Any /prometheus", I want it to be mapped to an private integration, i.e., an App load balancer.  How do I map to the root path of the load balancer? say  I want to map "execute_api.endpiont/prometheus/targets" to "load_balancer_endpoint/targets" (dropping the "prometheus") instead of "load_balancer_endpoint/prometheus/targets"?  Basically I want to start from the root of the load balancer.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

We can setup proxy at any resource, [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-http.html) is the tutorial

- Create a resource `/prometheus`
- Create another resource under `/prometheus` , check `Configure as proxy resource`. This will create an `ANY` method.
- Setup Endpoint URL in integreation request of ANY method as `http://my-test-api.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/{proxy}`

Now any api call to `https://abcabc123.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/mystage/prometheus/.....` to `http://my-test-api.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/....`

Comment: I am using the api gateway version 2, with private integration via VPC_LINK. It asks to provide the ARN of the load balancer, instead of the URL.

Comment: yaa. For private integration, we need to create vpc link to NLB/ALB from `VPC links` option on API Gateway console. Then create an integration to that vpc link